# How do I fetch data from api based on search of the user in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, native-base

The goal is to allow the user to input a keyword into a search bar, store the search word or phrase into a string and send a post request to to the movie server and display the results in a FlatList format.

I'm not skilled in javascript, but so far I was able to store the search input into a variable and confirmed it by console logging the search but using that variable to render and display the results in confusing

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { 
    View,
    Text,
    FlatList,
StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import { Container, Header,Item,Input, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, 
 Title } from 'native-base';




class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
        this.state = {text: ''};
        this.state = {
         dataSource: []
        }
      }
  renderItem = ({item}) => {

    return (

       <Text>{item.title}</Text>

)}

componentDidMount() {
    const apikey = "&apikey=thewdb"
    const url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s="
    fetch(url + this.state.text + url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=> {
        this.setState({
            dataSource: responseJson.Search

        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })


}


render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Header
                searchBar rounded
            >
                <Item>
                    <Icon name="ios-search" />
                    <Input 
                        placeholder="Type here to translate!"
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                    />
                </Item>
                <Button
                transparent
                onPress={()=> {
                        {console.log(this.state.text)}
                        }
                    }
                >
                    <Text>Search</Text>
                </Button>
            </Header>
            <FlatList
                style={{flex: 1, width:300}}
                data={this.state.dataSource}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key'+index}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                />
        </Container>
         );
     }
}

export default Search;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

My code is a bit sloppy so please forgive me on that, I'm still new to coding.

Comment: Would be great if you add a working copy in snack.expo.io

Comment: alright I will once I get it going. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you are fetching data from API on `componentDidMount` but it will be called only once (when component gets mounted).

So the best way to fix it is

1. Create a func called fetchData

```
  fetchData(text) {
    this.setState({ text });
    const apikey = '&apikey=thewdb';
    const url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=';
    fetch(url + text + url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: responseJson.Search,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

2. In onChangeText, call fetchData

```
  <Input
    placeholder="Type here to translate!"
    onChangeText={(text) => {
      this.fetchData(text);
    }}
  />
```

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but also not seeing any output. This seems to be the right answer but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Ooguro can you update your code with new changes? I want to see the code.